# Is there a way to parse category paths as route paths in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am building an online store and I'm using category paths like this `/electronics/phones/samsung` in my models.

What I want to do is have a route like this `/categories/electronics/phones/samsung` that retrieves all items that matches this category path.

I have implemented the way to actually find the items given the path but how would I go about parsing this as URL?

I'm using express framework for Node JS

Comment: Do you want to pass `/categories` as string but from any variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MongoDB as a Database try to order routes as it goes in the database. For example you have in DB:

```
"product": {"product1": { "product2": {...} }}
```

Yout route should be like **/product/product1/product2**

Go with: `req.originalUrl`

Then parse it like:

`req.originalUrl.split("/")`

and you'll get array:

`["","categories","electronics","phones","Samsung"]`

Comment: what should my route pattern look like?

Comment: Your pattern seems okay too. But, I usually do is like: `/categories/electronics/phones?manufacturer=samsung`.

Comment: No I mean how should I structure the pattern on the router it self? should it be like ```router.get("/category/:path")```

Comment: @AliGasimzade Yes, that seems fine in my opinion.

Comment: One note to anybody who's reading this. ```req.originalUrl()``` is not a method. You should go with ```req.originalUrl```

Comment: @AliGasimzade Oh sorry, I fix the typo :)

Comment: One more thing ```router.get("/category/:path")``` did not work for ```/category/path/like/this"```. Any solution for that?

Comment: @AliGasimzade If you have multiple paths you should use like: /category/:path1/:path2, etc.

Comment: I do not know how many paths I will have beforehand

Comment: @AliGasimzade 

Try with this: 


    `var paths = ['/path2', '/path3, ...'];

     paths.forEach(function(name) { app.get(name, function(req, res) { res.render(name) }) });`